# mybatis 3.1 + sprinng 3.2 properties

Tags: spring, properties, mybatis

We have 4 applications running on a Tomcat7 server. The existing applications work on Hibernate and Spring.
The backend is connected to a second database and some old schemas are kept here live. Each schema is called xxx_live and xxx_test.

When the Tomcat server starts, a JNDI property is set for the right environment.

- Test
- Local
- Live

The properties are parsed on an extention of the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer class:

```
public class GenericPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

private String application;
private String environment;
private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "environment";

public GenericPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(String application) throws IOException {
    this.application = application;

    this.environment = System.getProperty(ENVIRONMENT);
    if (this.environment == null) {
        this.environment = System.getenv().get(ENVIRONMENT);
    }
    initPropertySources();
}

/**
 * setup default properties configuration
 * Default configuration properties look like :
 * app-global.properties
 * app-environment.properties
 * jndi properties
 */
private void initPropertySources() throws IOException {

    MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();

    propertySources.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(new ClassPathResource(MessageFormat.format("properties/{0}-global.properties", application))));
    propertySources.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(new ClassPathResource(MessageFormat.format("properties/{0}/{1}.properties", environment, application))));
    propertySources.addLast(new NotFailingJndiPropertySource("jndi"));

    setPropertySources(propertySources);
    setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
}
}
```

Now we're migrating everything to MyBatis. Is there a way to inject or parse these properties into my XML configuration?
Something like:

```
<select id="findAllUsers" parameterType="list" resultType="user">
      SELECT * FROM ${mybatis.default_schema}.USER
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Definitely you can pass this property.

The function declaration in DAO layer (JAVA Mapper for mybatis in spring) would be like

```
List<User> findAllUsers(@Param("schemaName") String schemaName)
```

And when you call this function pass the schema name as argument.

Few Suggestions (Assuming you are new to MyBatis)

1. You should rather configure your Property using spring's util tag in context.xml
   i.e. `<util:properties id="mailProps" location="classpath:mail.properties" />`
2. Scan for Mappers & Autowire using spring (again in context.xml)

   ```
   <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
       <property name="basePackage" value="com.foo.bar" />
   </bean>
   ```

   Where `com.foo.bar` is package where you Java Interface's representing your XML are located.
   This way You will actually be using spring's benefits i.e. `DI / IOC`
3. `parameterType` would be `String` or `java.lang.String` not list.

If you need further help / any doubts feel free to ask back.

HTH
Thanks.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response.
I was thinking of the same solution but i don't like to put my schema name in the method var.
I like to separate my dao layer. Like this i can rollback to an other db framework in less then a day. 
I'm looking for a solution to put my props into the Mybatis scope.
The mappers i used like you showed above. Thanx for the other tip.